# Start a <p:selectCheckboxMenu> expanded?

Tags: jsf, user-interface, jsf-2, primefaces

I feel like this is a simple question, but all of my googling and reading has not presented an answer.  That being said, I am still very new to JSF (PF).

Anyways, I am using the [SelectCheckboxMenu](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectCheckboxMenu.jsf) component from [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) and want to know how I can start it "expanded" or "open" without requiring the click to open it up.

Here is how it looks normally when initially rendered:

[image: Movies Unexpanded Image]

Here is how I would like it to look when initially rendered, without using a mouseclick to expand it:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way that can do it :

```
<style>
    .start-expended.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-panel
    {
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<p:selectCheckboxMenu panelStyleClass="start-expended" label="Test">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="test" itemValue="test" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

Note the `panelStyleClass` attribute that is used only as a distinctive selector in case you have many components and only want to show particular ones open.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery (it's already in primefaces) on page load. You can either use the code below which will show all selectcheckbox menu panels, or you can replace the 
$(".ui-selectcheckboxmenu-panel") with $('#WHATEVERTHEELEMENTIDIS') - where WHATEVERTHEELEMENTIDIS is the full id of the panel within the component

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ui-selectcheckboxmenu-panel").show();

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it declaratively or server-side without using inline JS ?

Comment: @bulltorious without modifying the PrimeFaces component and adding such attribute, I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a widgetVar to your p:selectCheckBoxMenu and call show();

and another place, call

xisWidget.show();